# Tensor to categorical, tensorflow problem with fit.generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have a problem with create a one hot tensor for training multiclass segmentation. The pixels in the segmentation mask are labeled either {0, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240}, if I do

```
tf.utils.keras.to_categorical(masks, 6)
```

the code don't work. I also transform the pixel in the value {0,1,2,3,4,5}, and the code work but when I plot the layer 1 or 2 I don't see anything.
After I use:

```
tf.one_hot(masks,6)
```

This work fine but when I give to the `model.fit()` the generator with the result of this line my training stall.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that you really only have 6 different labels in your list and that they start at 0 and only range to num_classes-1.

> ```
> tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=None, dtype='float32')
> ```
>
> Args:
>
> - y : class vector to be converted into a matrix (integers from 0 to num_classes).
> - num_classes : total number of classes. If None, this would be inferred as the (largest number in y) + 1
>
> © TensorFlow: Large-scale machine learning on heterogeneous systems, 2015. (CC BY 4.0), Source: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/to_categorical

Otherwise it will fail. Besides, `tf.utils.keras` might be the wrong way round in your function call.

```
>>>import tensorflow as tf
>>>tf.keras.utils.to_categorical([0,1,2,3,4,5], 6)
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

works, but

```
>>>tf.keras.utils.to_categorical([0, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240], 6)
IndexError: index 200 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 6
```

fails. You could also set num_classes to `None`. This will work but it will also increase the length of your one hot encoded Labels to `max([0, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240]) + 1`

```
>>>tf.keras.utils.to_categorical([0, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240], None)
array([[1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.], ... ], dtype=float32)

# with
# len([1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]) == 241
```

You might use `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder` to prepare/normalise your labels:

> ```
> >>>from sklearn import preprocessing
> >>>le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
> >>>le.fit([1, 2, 2, 6])
> LabelEncoder()
> >>>le.classes_
> array([1, 2, 6])
> >>>le.transform([1, 1, 2, 6])
> array([0, 0, 1, 2]...)
> >>>le.inverse_transform([0, 0, 1, 2])
> array([1, 1, 2, 6])
> ```
>
> © 2007 - 2020, scikit-learn developers (BSD License), Source: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html